# emulate function call in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

(The following queries are extreme simplification of the actual ones, for sake of clear code)

I have a stored procedure which has a query in it:

```
SELECT
   f1,
   f2
FROM
   T1
WHERE
   T1.id IN (SELECT complex_id FROM t2 WHERE complex='condition')
```

I would like to reuse the inner query `(SELECT complex_id FROM t2 WHERE complex='condition')` in other stored procedures, but maintain it's syntax in **only one place**.
How would I achieve this, using DB objects (SP,Triggers etc) and **no** outside code (like PHP etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a view: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

```
CREATE VIEW reusable_query AS
SELECT complex_id FROM t2 WHERE complex='condition';
```

Then you can:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id IN (SELECT complex_id FROM reusable_query);
```

You could take this one step further with a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isInReusableQuery(param INT) RETURNS BOOL
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT;
    SELECT COUNT(complex_id) INTO cnt FROM reusable_query
    WHERE
        complex = 'condition'
        AND complex_id = param;
    RETURN cnt > 0;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Which allows you to do things like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE isInReusableQuery(id);
```

I would probably not recommend the latter, though. Querying the view from a stored function may prevent some [optimisations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-algorithms.html).

Comment: I really liked your second option (although it is not a general solution, it is enough for what I need).